# Retrieving database meta information using Java EE/JPA

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, restful-architecture, database-metadata

I need to be able to retrieve database information from any type of database and return this information via a restful service (using Glassfish and JAX-RS).

The information I need includes:

- Database names
- Table names
- Column names and properties

I am currently looking into [DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) and seems to provide what I require.

However, I wanted to check if there are alternatives I should be considering (such as JPA2).

Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I settled on using [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/). It is highly configurable and provides me with everything I need.